# Running Python script in Excel

Tags: python, excel, vba

I would like to run Python script by clicking button in my Excel spreadsheet (by assigning macro to the button). I was trying to that this way like below but Python is running for a less than second and nothing happens... Is there any way to insist on script to wait until it will be finished? Thank you in advance.

```vb
Sub Script_Launcher()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    PythonExe = """<path to Python>"""

    PythonScript = "<path to my script>"

    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
End Sub
```

This is my Python script to download specific attachments from Outlook, add new column at the beginning and save under specific folder.

```py
import win32com.client
import os
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

print (dt.datetime.now())

# setup range for outlook to search emails (so we don't go through the entire inbox)
lastWeekDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 1)
lastWeekDateTime = lastWeekDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')

# Select main Inbox
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

# Optional:  Select main Inbox, look in subfolder "Test"
#inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["Test"]

messages = inbox.Items

# Only search emails in the time range above:
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastWeekDateTime +"'")

print ('Reading Inbox, including Inbox Subfolders...')

# Download a select attachment ---------------------------------------
# Create a folder to capture attachments.
folderInv = r'<Path for Inventory files>'
folderRes = r'<Path for Reservations files>'
#if not os.path.exists(Myfolder): os.makedirs(Myfolder)

try:
    for message in list(messages):
        try:
            s = message.sender
            s = str(s)

            for att in message.Attachments:
                if 'Inventory for Dashboard Refresh' in att.FileName:                    
                # Give each attachment a path and filename
                    print('Sender:' , message.sender)
                    outfile_name1 = folderInv + '\\'  + att.FileName
                    att.SaveASFile(outfile_name1)
                    df = pd.read_csv(outfile_name1)
                    df.insert(0, 'Date', dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
                    df.to_csv(outfile_name1, index=False)
                    print('Saved file:', outfile_name1)
                elif 'Reservations for Dashboard Refresh' in att.FileName:
                    print('Sender:' , message.sender)
                    outfile_name1 = folderRes + '\\' + att.FileName
                    att.SaveASFile(outfile_name1)
                    df = pd.read_csv(outfile_name1)
                    df.insert(0, 'Date', dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
                    df.to_csv(outfile_name1, index=False)
                    print('Saved file:', outfile_name1)


        except Exception as e:
            print("type error: " + str(e))
            x=1

except Exception as e:
    print("type error: " + str(e))
    x=1
```

Comment: Set the optional parameter `bWaitOnReturn` to `True`? You could also investigate something like [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/0.16.5/vba.html) -- an add-in for calling Python functions from VBA.

Comment: You mean that it should look like 
```vba
objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript, bWaitOnReturn = True
```

i was trying like that but it is not working :(

Comment: Did you use `bWaitOnReturn := True` ? (note the colon before the equals sign). There is also the `Exec` method, which gives you a bit more control than `Run`

Comment: I put it this way ```vba 
objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript, bWaitOnReturn:=True ```
 and I am receiving an error "Run-time error '448': Named argument not found"

Comment: Maybe simply `WaitOnReturn`. The documentation seems hard to google. You could also use `vba objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript, ,True` (note the double commas -- it is the third argument.

Comment: [Here is the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//d5fk67ky%28v%3dvs.85%29). For some reason, the official documentation isn't being maintained any more. Microsoft seems to be moving away from supporting VBScript. It looks like the third parameter is not a named parameter, so you would need to pass `True` as the third argument.

Comment: Thanks for help. However, it is still the same :( Python is running and turning off immediately.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with your Python script? Without a [mcve] it is hard to say much.

Comment: John, I edited my main post with Python code. It is normally running through Python IDLE.

Comment: Running it in IDLE isn't a good analog for running it with `.Run`. If you just click on the icon for that Python script -- the window it runs in will close instantly. Your script *is* running. You just don't have any output to capture. You could put something like `response = input("Hit enter to exit")` at the bottom of the python script. At the very least, keeping the window open like that will allow you to see what Python is printing.

Comment: Thank you for help. The problem was also the path which contained spaces, when I moved it to the path which doesn't contain spaces it works :)